# NSViewController reference cycle with storyboards

Tags: macos, swift, osx-yosemite, appkit

NSViewController, when instantiated from storyboards under Swift, seems to have a reference cycle somewhere.

Calling the following code multiple times will instantiate and set a new view controller, but the old view controller is never dealloced. In the code, `containerViewController` is an NSViewController which should contain a single NSViewController, `containerView` is a subview within `containerViewController`, and `identifier` is the storyboard identifier to instantiate.

```
// Remove any sub viewcontrollers and their views
for viewController in containerViewController.childViewControllers as [NSViewController] {
    viewController.view.removeFromSuperview()
    viewController.removeFromParentViewController()
}
// Create and set up the new view controller and view.
let viewController = storyboard!.instantiateControllerWithIdentifier(identifier) as NSViewController
let view = viewController.view
view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
containerView.addSubview(viewController.view)
containerViewController.addChildViewController(viewController)
containerView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|[view]|", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: ["view": view]))
containerView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|[view]|", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: ["view": view]))
```

(Sample project no longer available)

I used an Apple TSI and they agree it's a bug, which I have filed, but I expected someone else to have come up against this by now seeing as NSViewControllers and storyboards are now the de facto on OSX. How have you worked around this problem? Or does it not affect anyone else and I am doing something wrong?

Pre-bounty edit: Each view controller must be able to link to any other view controller from code as the destination is determined on the fly. This seems to remove segues as an option.

**Bug fixed**

As of Xcode 6.3 this is no longer a bug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another answer.

It seems, only the **segues defined on Storyboard** can perform view controller deallocation.
So, Here is a very ugly but working workaround.

[image: screenshot]

```
class DismissSegue: NSStoryboardSegue {

    var nextViewControllerIdentifier:String?

    override func perform() {
        let src = self.sourceController as NSViewController
        let windowController = src.view.window!.windowController() as TopLevelWindowController

        src.view.removeFromSuperview()
        src.removeFromParentViewController()

        if let identifier = nextViewControllerIdentifier {
            windowController.setNewViewController(identifier)
        }
    }
}

class TopLevelWindowController: NSWindowController {

    var containerView: NSView!
    var containerViewController: ContainerViewController! {
        didSet {
            setNewViewController("FirstView")
        }
    }

    func setNewViewController(identifier: String) {
        // Create and set up the new view controller and view.
        let viewController = storyboard!.instantiateControllerWithIdentifier(identifier) as NSViewController
        let view = viewController.view
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        containerView.addSubview(viewController.view)
        containerViewController.addChildViewController(viewController)
        containerView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|[view]|", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: ["view": view]))
        containerView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|[view]|", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: ["view": view]))
    }
}

class ContainerViewController: NSViewController {

    @IBOutlet var containerView: NSView!

    override func viewDidAppear() {
        super.viewDidAppear()
        if let window = view.window {
            if let topLevelWindowController = window.windowController() as? TopLevelWindowController {
                topLevelWindowController.containerView = containerView
                topLevelWindowController.containerViewController = self
            }
        }
    }

}

class FirstViewController: NSViewController {

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        let pointerAddress = NSString(format: "%p", unsafeBitCast(self, Int.self))
        NSLog("First VC init at \(pointerAddress)")
    }

    deinit {
        let pointerAddress = NSString(format: "%p", unsafeBitCast(self, Int.self))
        NSLog("First VC de-init at \(pointerAddress)")
    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: NSStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if let segue = segue as? DismissSegue {
            segue.nextViewControllerIdentifier = "SecondView"
        }
    }
}

class SecondViewController: NSViewController {

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        let pointerAddress = NSString(format: "%p", unsafeBitCast(self, Int.self))
        NSLog("Second VC init at \(pointerAddress)")
    }

    deinit {
        let pointerAddress = NSString(format: "%p", unsafeBitCast(self, Int.self))
        NSLog("Second VC de-init at \(pointerAddress)")
    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: NSStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if let segue = segue as? DismissSegue {
            segue.nextViewControllerIdentifier = "FirstView"
        }
    }
}
```

Procedure for modifying your Storyboard:

1. Disconnect `@IBAction` from buttons.
2. Create "DUMMY" view controller scene with normal `NSViewController`.
3. Connect custom segues from buttons to "DUMMY".
4. Configure these segue as shown.

---

Please let me know if this solution doesn't meet your demand.

Comment: Wonderful! While this is, as you say, an ugly workaround, it means I can ship my app without huge re-working. In my implementation, I defined the segues at view controller level, kept the IBActions and called performSegueWithIdentifier where I would normally have called setNewViewController, so minimal code disruption. Thank you very much for coming up with this creative solution, I would never have thought of it.

Comment: There seems to have been a regression since this answer. I revisited my old sample project using your method of segues and the viewcontrollers no longer deallocate. Would you mind running your solution again to see whether it's just me?

Comment: Seems working in my environment - Xcode 6.1.1 and Xcode 6.2 beta, OS X 10.10.1.

Comment: Here is the project file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/35ufw44t9iu87mj/NonReleasingViewControllers_fixed.zip?dl=0

Comment: Perfect. The project file helped me find my problem (errant lines in the storyboard file which a diff located). Now it works just great again. Your continued help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

This might not solve your problem, but the only workaround I found is:

- Embed initial view controller using "Container View"
- No `@IBAction`
- Use custom `NSStoryboardSegue` to Switch between view controllers.

Something like this:

[image: screenshot]

```
import Cocoa

class TopLevelWindowController: NSWindowController {
}
class ContainerViewController: NSViewController {
}

class FirstViewController: NSViewController {
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        let pointerAddress = NSString(format: "%p", unsafeBitCast(self, Int.self))
        NSLog("First VC init at \(pointerAddress)")
    }
    deinit {
        let pointerAddress = NSString(format: "%p", unsafeBitCast(self, Int.self))
        NSLog("First VC de-init at \(pointerAddress)")
    }
}

class SecondViewController: NSViewController {
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        let pointerAddress = NSString(format: "%p", unsafeBitCast(self, Int.self))
        NSLog("Second VC init at \(pointerAddress)")
    }
    deinit {
        let pointerAddress = NSString(format: "%p", unsafeBitCast(self, Int.self))
        NSLog("Second VC de-init at \(pointerAddress)")
    }
}

class MySegue: NSStoryboardSegue {
    override func perform() {

        let source = self.sourceController as NSViewController
        let destination = self.destinationController as NSViewController

        if let containerViewController = source.parentViewController {

            source.view.removeFromSuperview()
            source.removeFromParentViewController()

            let view = destination.view
            let containerView = containerViewController.view

            view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            containerView.addSubview(view)
            containerView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|[view]|", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: ["view": view]))
            containerView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|[view]|", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: ["view": view]))
            containerViewController.addChildViewController(destination)
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I very very much like this idea, but in my situation, the destination view controller is not known at design time - it depends on data being loaded during app execution. Hence, it has to go through a central 'routing' process like in my `TopLevelWindowController.setNewViewController()` method. I tried creating a custom MySegue inside of the routing method, but it appears the problem is with `instantiateControllerWithIdentifier` because as soon as that method is called, the reference cycle starts.

Comment: Yeah, with my tests, wrapping with segue programmatically doesn't even help :(